# What causes MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

What causes `MissingMethodException` within view for MVC/ASP.NET?

Encountered a strange issue today. Within my view model, I had a property whose signature I changed. It originally returned `IEnumerable<Thing>`:

```
public IEnumerable<OtherThing> Things
{
    get
    {
        // Code goes here …
    }
}
```

… and I changed the return type to `IEnumerable<OtherThing>`:

```
public IEnumerable<OtherThing> Things
{
    get
    {
        // Code goes here …
    }
}
```

Compilation went all fine and dandy. The issue surfaced when I loaded the page that accesses Things. Specifically, I got a YSOD caused by a `MissingMethodException` inside a partial view I rendered via `@Html.RenderPartial()`:

```
// Inside my partial view
@foreach (var thing in Model.Things)
{
    // Rest of view code …
}
```

The offending code is the foreach loop. The `MissingMethodException` complains it was looking for the signature `public IEnumerable<Thing> Things`, but it found `public IEnumerable<OtherThing> Things` instead.

After much struggling and confusion, I typed some non-sense into the partial view, deleted that non-sense, and re-saved the file. Voila. `MissingMethodException` gone.

I solved the problem, but I feel robbed of an answer. Why was the view expecting `IEnumerable<Thing>`? Is it something to do with `var`? Was `var` cached as `IEnumerable<Thing>` on the view? If so, how are Razor partial views cached? And where?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling the Partial view ? What type it was bound to ?

Comment: I rendered the partial view via `Html.RenderPartial("_MyPartial", Model);`, where Model is the view model that contains the Things property.

Comment: what is `_MyPartial` bound to ? what type ?

Comment: `_MyPartial` is bound with `@model MyViewModel`, where `MyViewModel` is the class that contains `Things`.

Or do you mean something else?